# Regular expression to separate phrases that could have similar starts

Tags: regex

I'm admittedly not great with regex. So let's say I have a sentence that says

```
At the barn, CAT goes meow. DOG goes woof. WOLF howls. WOLF DOG howls and woofs. DOG goes bark. SHEEP goes bah.
```

Basically I need the phrases separated out. The animal would be the delimiter.

I have used this regex to get this far,

```
(?=CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP).+?(?=CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP|$)
```

But what I am getting is

```
CAT goes meow. 
DOG goes woof. 
WOLF howls. 
WOLF 
DOG howls and woofs. 
DOG goes bark. 
SHEEP goes bah.
```

Since WOLF and DOG are delimiters on their own, how do I change the regex I have so that the output would be

```
CAT goes meow. 
DOG goes woof. 
WOLF howls. 
WOLF DOG howls and woofs. 
DOG goes bark. 
SHEEP goes bah.
```

Comment: `(WOLF DOG|WOLF|DOG)` prefers `WOLF DOG` but will match any one out of the three.

Comment: Maybe `\b(?:CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP)\b.*?[.?!](?=\s*(?:CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP)\b|$)`? See https://regex101.com/r/iDpgUO/1

Comment: If you want the preceding animal to be including in the output, why are you using a lookahead?

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

`(((CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP)\s)+[^\.]*\.)`

Fiddle https://regex101.com/r/ChalA5/1

Comment: This seems to work a little better, but there aren't going to be periods at the end of the phrases. Basically I would want everything between the delimiters. Finding a new delimiter would indicate a new match.

Comment: In question you have stated the input data and the expected result and it contains dots. If there is no dots (and the dots is a delimiter in your question, not keywords), it would be another reqular expression at all

Comment: To get all between keywords use this regex `(((CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP)\s)+[^(CAT|DOG|WOLF|SHEEP)]*)`. Fiddle 
https://regex101.com/r/ddEa7f/1